# Triangle inequality with complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

Okay so I know that:

$$|z|-|z_0| \leq |z-z_0|$$ and similarly that

$$|z_0|-|z| \leq |z-z_0|$$ but in my book it states that since this is true then it is obviously true that $$||z|-|z_0||\leq |z-z_0|$$

yet this is not immediate to me and I tried to prove it but couldn't any hints?

Comment: What you know gives you that $$-|z-z_0|\leq |z|-|z_0| \leq |z-z_0|$$

Comment: Oh so multiply the second inequality by $-1$ then use the property of the modulus function. $$|a| \leq b \implies -b \leq a \leq b$$. Thank you.

Comment: Shortly: $a,-a\le|a|$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see it is to remember that:
$$\lvert x\rvert=\max\{x,-x\}.$$
Now, you proved that $\lvert z\rvert-\lvert z_0\rvert\leq\lvert z-z_0\rvert$ and $-(\lvert z\rvert-\lvert z_0\rvert)\leq\lvert z-z_0\rvert$, whence
$$\bigl\lvert\lvert z\rvert-\lvert z_0\rvert\bigr\rvert=\max\bigl\{\lvert z\rvert-\lvert z_0\rvert,-(\lvert z\rvert-\lvert z_0\rvert)\bigr\}\leq\lvert z-z_0\rvert$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the definition of the absolute value $\vert\cdot\vert$:
$$\vert x\vert=\begin{cases}
x & \mbox{ if } x\geq0\\
-x & \mbox{ if } x<0
\end{cases}$$